# is this gyro sensor suitable for turtlebot?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all !

I'd like to know if this gyro sensor is suitable for turtlrbot 1 or not ?
Voltage: 5V
Analog output

the link describing this gyro is in the comment.

waiting for you answers.

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146461/is-this-gyro-sensor-suitable-for-turtlebot-??/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2014-03-31**:
http://support.robotis.com/en/
follow this hyper links: Product Information -> ROBOT PARTS -> Sensor -> Gyro Sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer gives a good overview of what the requirements are for the turtlebot1 gyro: http://answers.ros.org/question/115741/parallax-gyro-work-on-turtlebot-1/#116621

Looking at your gyro ( http://support.robotis.com/en/product/auxdevice/sensor/dxl_gyro.htm ) and doing a little math, it looks like it reads 1V/300 degrees/sec ~= 3.3 mV/degree/sec. Not quite as sensitive as the original gyro; you may have to make some adjustments.

There are also a number of other questions the discuss alternate gyros for the turtlebot:

http://answers.ros.org/question/31341/gyro-for-turtlebot/ ( http://www.pololu.com/product/1255/ )
http://answers.ros.org/question/12745/gyro-for-turtlebot/ (discusses adjusting the gyro sensitivity)
http://answers.ros.org/question/11161/gyro-substitute-for-turtlebot/?answer=16553#post-id-16553
http://answers.ros.org/question/10437/using-a-different-gyro-on-a-turtlebot/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2014-04-10**:
Thank you for your answer ahendrix :) it really helps me .

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2014-06-05**:
Hi ahendrix,

You told me that I may have to make some adjustments to work correctly with my this sensor.
I'm confused, what kind of adjustments I shoud do.

This gyro doesn't work for me. Using it, my maps was really a mess ! :(

I need your help.

Kind regard.